# Struggling with regex in yahoo pipe

Tags: regex, rss, web-scraping, yahoo-pipes

I'm using Yahoo Pipes to build a scraper that would scrape our company micro-site via xPath and generate an RSS feed that I can then embed on the main site.

So far I got as far as scraping the Job title and location from the page but I can't get the items to link out to the micro-site.

Here's my pipe so far: http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=2bb5b8fedd0064b64d0e8861e3fc8fd5

I think I need to extract the href link from each node and then apply regex but I really can't get my head around it.

The link looks like this in the code: www2.jobs.badenochandclark.ch/JavaScript:OpenAssignment('a960c93a-11fe-4751-bc27-83a48429c3ba',%20'/Jobs/Details/a960c93a-11fe-4751-bc27-83a48429c3ba');

But I'm struggling to generate a regex that would basically do this:
www2.jobs.badenochandclark.ch/<strike>JavaScript:OpenAssignment('a960c93a-11fe-4751-bc27-83a48429c3ba',%20'</strike>/Jobs/Details/a960c93a-11fe-4751-bc27-83a48429c3ba<strike>');</strike>

So I'm stuck on how to extract a link and then how to build that on to the pipe. Any help or nudge in the right direction would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go..
http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=d564b802185d5777d757ed4189470941

Used slightly less complicated code in the regex module. It often being easier to erase the code you do not want than trying to extract and assign to a variable

in **plx.link.href** find this-> **JavaScript(.+)Jobs**  replace with->**jobs**

in **plx.link.href**  find this-> **\'\);**  replace with->*leave blank*

the trailing bit of code '); requires the backslashes as **'** and **)** are control charecters adding the backslash  **\** makes regex read them literlally as text characters.

This bit of regex **a(.+?)b**  means match or grab everything between a & b and comes in handy for this sort of thing a lot.

Comment: Thanks! I had no idea about a(.+?)b. The solution works amazingly!

Answer (score 0):

Full-fledged URL-parsing isn't simple, but given enough constraints it becomes manageable.

For example, if you know

1. that `JavaScript:OpenAssignment(` always follows a `/`,
2. that the first argument is always a hexadecimal+dashes string in quotes,
3. that the second argument (at least the portion you need) is also in quotes,
4. and that you can discard the remainder of URL after the "function,"

then something like this might be a starting point:

```
\/JavaScript:OpenAssignment\([^'"]*['"][0-9a-fA-F\-]+['"][^,)]*,[^'")]*['"]([0-9a-fA-F\-]+)['"].*
```

Then, `$1` would contain the match you desire to keep.  The explanation follows.

```
\/                           Slashes need to be escaped (usually).
JavaScript:OpenAssignment    Our function of interest.
\(                           Parentheses need to be escaped too.
[^'"]*                       We're looking for a quote next, so ignore any
                             string of non-quotes, e.g. %20.
['"]                         A quote character.
[0-9a-fA-F\-]+               A hexadecimal-and-dashes string.
['"]                         A quote character.
[^,)]*                       We're looking for a comma next, so ignore any
                             string of non-quotes, e.g., again, %20.
,                            A comma character.
[^'"]*                       We're looking for a quote again, so ignore any
                             string of non-quotes, e.g. %20.
['"]                         A quote character.
([0-9a-fA-F\-]+)             A hexadecimal-and-dashes string, this time captured.
['"]                         A quote character.
.*                           The rest of the string that we don't care about.
```